# CSS different transition delay for each child element, but reverse the delays when the transition reverses

Tags: css, animation, delay, transition

I want to animate a drop-down. When the drop-down is *expanding*, each list element should be delayed slightly more than the previous one. When it is *contracting*, these delays should happen in the reverse order.

I.e:

**Delays on child elements when expanding:**

1. 0ms
2. 50ms
3. 100ms

**Delays on child elements when contracting:**

1. 100ms
2. 50ms
3. 0ms

I can program the expanding logic with a simple `nth-child` statement:

```
ul li:nth-child(2) {
    transition-delay: 50ms;
}
ul li:nth-child(3) {
    transition-delay: 100ms;
}
```

But I'm not sure how to do the contracting animation.

What is the best way to approach this?

Comment: show full code .

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a class when it's expanded or collapsed and play the animation the other way depending on that class:

```js
var btn = document.querySelector('button');
var menu = document.querySelector('ul');

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  menu.classList.toggle('hidden');
});
```

```css
ul.hidden li {
  opacity: 0;
}
ul li {
  opacity: 1;
}

/* Expand */
ul li:nth-child(1) {
  transition-delay: 200ms;
}
ul li:nth-child(2) {
  transition-delay: 400ms;
}
ul li:nth-child(3) {
  transition-delay: 600ms;
}

/* Collapse */
ul.hidden li:nth-child(1) {
  transition-delay: 600ms;
}
ul.hidden li:nth-child(2) {
  transition-delay: 400ms;
}
ul.hidden li:nth-child(3) {
  transition-delay: 200ms;
}
```

```html
<button type="button">Click</button>
<ul class="hidden">
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
</ul>
```